# Cannot read property 'X' of undefined Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to A2 and TypeScript. I don't understand why my user is null at that point. I've managed to get rid of the error by using the elvis operator,but I don't know how to fix it. Each appointment has the user set, but I can't 
understand why is it null. Thanks!

appointment.component.ts

```
export class AppointmentComponent implements OnInit {appointmentList: 
Object[];

constructor(private appointmentService: AppointmentService) {
    this.getAppointmentList();
}

getAppointmentList() {
    this.appointmentService.getAppointmentList().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.appointmentList = 
JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))._body);
        },
        error => console.log(error)
    )

}
```

appointment.component.html

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let appointment of appointmentList">
        <td>{{appointment.id}}</td>
        <td>{{appointment.user?.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{appointment.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
        <td>{{appointment.hour}}</td>
        <td>{{appointment.description}}</td>
        <td>{{appointment.confirmed}}</td>
        <td [hidden]="appointment.confirmed"><a 
(click)="confirmAppointment(appointment.id)" style="cursor: 
pointer;">Confirm</a></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

appointment.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AppointmentService {

constructor (private http:Http){}

getAppointmentList() {
let url = "http://localhost:8181/api/appointment/all";
return this.http.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
} }
```

Error stacktrace

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppointmentComponent class 
AppointmentComponent - inline template:17:7 caused by: Cannot read property 
'firstName' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
at View_AppointmentComponent1.detectChangesInternal 
(/AppModule/AppointmentComponent/component.ngfactory.js:113)
at View_AppointmentComponent1.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
at View_AppointmentComponent1.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (view_container.js:67)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppointmentComponent0. 
detectChangesInternal 
(/AppModule/AppointmentComponent/component.ngfactory.js:318)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges 
(view.js:410)
at 
CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppointmentComponent_Host0.
detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppointmentComponent/host.ngfactory.js:29)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (view_container.js:67)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal 
(/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:56)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
```

UPDATE

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/api/appointment")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public class AppointmentResource {

@Autowired
private AppointmentService appointmentService;

@Autowired
private SendEmail serviceSendEmail;

@RequestMapping("/all")
public List<Appointment> findAppointmentList() {
    List<Appointment> appointmentList = appointmentService.findAll();

    return appointmentList;
}}
```

Comment: Post the complete and exact error message and stack trace.

Comment: And seriously: `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))._body`? How about `res.json()`, as documented?

Comment: I've updated the post, but I don't have the error anymore because I am using the ? operator, but I don't understand why the user is null. Thanks for res.json().

Comment: also post your API methd signature.

Comment: There is no way we can explain why the user is undefied. The problem is at server-side: you're receiving appointments with an undefined user from the server.

Comment: I used the debug mode on the server and each appointment has an user :(

Comment: Then its not correctly serialized and sent to the browser. Look at the JSON received in your browser dev tools. Maybe Appointment doesn't have a getUser() method. Maybe user is annotated with `@JsonIgnore`. Maybe the JsonProperty name is different.

Comment: Thank you! I was using @JsonBackReference in a wrong way.